Featured and Hot Meta Posts votes count CSS style bug
Once a 3-digit (or larger, though unlikely) vote count is reached the formatting becomes awkward.


This has already been brought up some time ago with no reaction from SE: The Hot Meta Posts vote counter is too narrow.

"some time ago" - almost 6-8 years ago
